# Can't I track a simple button click event on firebase without linking it to BigQuery?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

Let us say my app has a registration button. I'd like to know how many users clicked on it. Simple as that.

Below given is the code I use, Could I be doing something wrong?

```
 mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
 mFirebaseAnalytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);

 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "Register");
 bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "RegistrationCompleted");
 bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "Button");                        
 mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
```

Comment: Did you find an answer yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Audience filter](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317509?hl=en) for users that have the event params that you are trying to track. This will give you the number of users who click on the button on your Developer Console under Audience tab without querying from BigQuery.